# how to change element inside table using java script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have such a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<table class="demo">
    <div>
        <a>link1</a>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</table>

<a>link2</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].style.color = "red";
 }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to change only these links which are inside the `table`. Is it possible using `js`? How to do this?

Comment: Suggest using `document.querySelectorAll('table.demo a');` to get all your links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid, [div](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html#div) can't be a child of [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html#table).

Since you are not using any table constructs change the `table` to `div`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].style.color = "red";
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div class="demo">
  <div>
    <a>link1</a>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<a>link2</a>
```

The html rendered when using markup is as shown in the below image, if you look at it the `div` is rendered outside of the `table`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a div can be inside a td tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<table class="demo">
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<a>link1</a>
<p>text</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a>link2</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].style.color = "red";
 }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works then. IBM Websphere Portal uses such a construction.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of span tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<table class="demo">
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<a><span id="link1">link1</span></a>
<p>text</b>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a>link2</a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML="abcd";

 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The button click will change the link using js. You can do any kind of css changes using the id of span.
Kindly upvote if this solves your query.